# File not moving from folder to another

Tags: java, file-rename

I am trying to find the latest 10 files from a folder and then move it to another folder, I am able to find the latest 10 files but the files won't move to another folder, renameTo is always returning false and canWrite returns true.

What could be the possible reasons and solutions?

```
    class MoveFiles
{
    int numOfForms;
    String source;
    String destination;
    static String finalDest;
    String stateName;

    MoveFiles(int numOfForms,String source,String destination, String stateName)
    {
        System.out.println("Move Files Constructor");
        this.numOfForms=numOfForms;
        this.source=source;
        this.destination=destination;
        this.stateName=stateName;
    }
    public void mFile()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting moving files");
        finalDest = "C:\\PDF\\"+destination+"\\"+stateName;
        File f = new File(finalDest);
        System.out.println("Can Write ? : "+f.canWrite());
        System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
        for ( int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            File moveit = MoveFiles.lastFileModified(source);
            System.out.println(moveit.renameTo(f));
        }
    }

    public static File lastFileModified(String dir) {
        File fl = new File(dir);
        File[] files = fl.listFiles(new FileFilter() {          
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isFile();
            }
        });
        long lastMod = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        File choice = null;
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.lastModified() > lastMod) {
                choice = file;
                lastMod = file.lastModified();
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```

Comment: `f.mkdirs()` creates directories, `moveit.renameTo(f)` is attempting to rename file as already existing directory (not to that directory). To get better info about problem code handling file is facing use file API provided in Java 7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Comment: Misunderstand the how `rename` works.  Basically you're renaming your files to `C:\\PDF\\" + destination + "\\" + stateName`, which is a directory and which already exists, this is not a valid operation.  Instead, you want to use something like `File dest = new File(f, moveit.getName());` to specify the path AND the file name to which the file should be renamed, then you use `moveit.renameTo(dest)` to physically rename/move the file